# Intelligent Agents using Jade framework

Tags: artificial-intelligence, agents-jade, multi-agent

I want to develop a multi-agent system and I want to run different agents from different containers. I'm using eclipse with Jade framework for this and i have no idea how to configure the "run configuration" for the project in order to accomplish this. So far I have this: -gui -container main:Sender;a1:Receiver;a2:Pong and I want to put agents a1 and a2 in a separate container. Please help.

Comment: You can try to follow the Jade Primer instructions. Look at Jade Options: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/primer2.html#2.5 - You can also go further looking at http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JADEAdmin/startJade.html . So, you can simply call  -gui -container -container-name abc main:Sender;a1:Receiver and another call -gui -container -container-name def a2:Pong

Answer (score 0):

When starting a new jade project I usually create a Coordinator agent with the methods to launch and destroy other agents. I think this is good practice as you can extend these methods to other agents if need be.

Comment: I hope that the OP hasn't been waiting all this time for an answer :-(

Comment: Well I'd still recommend using a coordinator anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I hope that this will help.

1. First Run the Agent jade graphical user interface (Ejade) (By Installing the Ejade Library)
   or you can run it on the console:
     `C:\java jade.Boot -gui` (You have to fix the system variable path  to `"C:\..\jade.far"` and create a variable name `classpath = "C:\..\jdk7\"`)
2. Run the code that allows you to create a new container to deploy on it your agents.

   ```
   import jade.core.ProfileImpl;
   import jade.core.Runtime;
   import jade.domain.ams;
   import jade.wrapper.AgentContainer;
   import jade.wrapper.AgentController;

   public class ContainerDeploy {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           try{
               Runtime runtime=Runtime.instance();
               ProfileImpl profileImpl = new ProfileImpl(false);
               profileImpl.setParameter(ProfileImpl.MAIN_HOST, "localhost");
               AgentContainer     agentContainer=runtime.createAgentContainer(profileImpl);

               AgentController agentcontroller1 = agentContainer.createNewAgent("Name of Agent", "com.package.AgentClass", new Object[]{});

               agentController1.start();
           }catch(Exception e) {
               System.out.println("Runtime Error\t");
               e.printStackTrace();
           } 
       }
   }
   ```